# Disabling a button but visually keeping it as if it wasn't disabled

Tags: python, button, user-interface, tkinter

for my board game, I need to press a certain button and after that, disable it (to prevent the user or the computer to place a "peace" in the same place). The problem I have with this is basically design-wise: as you would know, when a button is disabled in tkinter, it turns grayed-out, kinda "visually blocking" the piece I placed... Here is an image of what I'm talking about:

[image]

My question is, how would I disable a button, but keep it as if it wasn't disabled? I searched and the only answer I came about was basically getting rid of the button and replacing it with an image... If that's my best bet, how would I do this? the grid is created with a for loop that fills a list with buttons, and then displays them into a frame using the grid() method. This would look like:

[image]

Is there another way to achieve this with tkinter methods? I would rather not change the buttons to an image with a bound event, that seems too complicated given that I'd have to mess with my loop. Thanks!!

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can flag it as pressed, and not do anything in your click event if it's been pressed before.

Comment: To elaborate on @jadkik94's comment: Give each game piece button an additional `game_state` attribute and check it in the `command` function (while never setting their regular `tk.Button.state` attribute to `tk.DISABLED` which would cause them to gray out and become unresponsive).

Comment: Thanks for your inputs! so, basically, if game_state is 1 (after it was pressed), make the button not have a callback function (specified in the command part)? is this attribute passed in the command=lambda part of my for loop? sorry, my programming knowledge is not the greatest.

Comment: Not exactly. Leave the callback function in place at all times. Within it, check the `game_state` of the button instance it corresponds to. You can pass the button to the callback via a lambda with a default argument. If you post some code -- for your Buttons at least -- I could probably make this more clear. This is essentially the last option @Bryan Oakley is talking about in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out in order to disable the button but keeping its appearance, you have to disable its callback to make it "unresponsive" (as stated by @Bryan Oakley and @martineau, thanks!) and also change its 'relief' as to make it stay "fixed" (it kind of shifts into the bottom right corner, but that's good enough).

Imagine you have this generic button:

```
button = tkinter.Button(frame, height=0, bg='blue',\
                    activebackground='blue',width = 0, text = " ", image = self.blank, \
                    command=lambda row=row_index, \
                        column=column_index: \
                        self.button_clicked(row,column))
```

Now when you want to disable it but keeping its original appearance, you change the following attributes of the button:

```
button['command'] = 0 #this disables the callback
button['relief'] = 'sunken' #makes the button fixed
```

As easy as that! thanks!

Comment: Setting it to zero is very odd. A better value would be to set it to `None`.

Answer (score 3):

You can control the foreground and background colors with a variety of options, such as `foreground`, `background`, `disabledforeground`, and `highlightbackground`. Have you tried setting any of those to get the visual behavior you want?

You also have the option of disabling the callback, so the button will press but it won't do anything. To disable it, simply configure the `command` option to be `None`:

```
the_button.configure(command=None)
```

Comment: I tried all the button specific options that control the background with no luck unfortunately. I'm trying to work around your last suggested option, but I think I don't understand completely how could I do this. I'll keep trying, thanks!